# Zabbix Wesite monitoring email notification

Tags: web, monitoring, zabbix

Configured Zabbix server to monitor websites if status code 200 is ok or not. I did created also the triggers and actions like you can view in the screenshots but so far still no email notification at all, email server work ok.

[image]

Configured Trigger
[image]

Configure Actions
[image]
[image]

Any though on this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Receiving email is a separate step than configuring web monitoring for the website. Please refer to this link to set up email notification for Zabbix Alerts. https://techexpert.tips/zabbix/zabbix-email-notification-setup/

Comment: So when trigger activate do you see any action associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your SMTP server settings, add the recipient email in the desired user's media and configure an action accordingly.

The [quickstart guide](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/quickstart/notification) covers all the required steps.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i did setup the smtp, all the other default triggers does work correctly. just the web triggers, does not work